# how to restrict titan when adding a vertex without unique property key

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, rexster

I want to put a restriction in titan graph while adding a new vertex with out unique property key.

**Eg: In my titan graph "aid" is unique property key and if I try to add any vertex thru gremlin or rexster without using "aid" it should stop.**

Steps I followed:

```
mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()   
aid = mgmt.makePropertyKey('aid').dataType(String.class).make()
mgmt.buildIndex('byAid',Vertex.class).addKey(aid).unique().buildCompositeIndex()

mgmt.commit()

gremlin>g.addVertex([aid:'aid91']);  
==>v[229640]  

*gremlin>g.addVertex([name:'srinivas']);  
==>v[246024]*
```

I want to restrict the second step if "aid" is not provided.

Can you guys help me to know the solution for this?
Thanking you in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do that kind of data validation at the application-level.  Neither Titan, nor the TinkerPop stack, provide a way to ensure that a field is present when a new vertex is added.

The syntax you are using seems to indicate that you are using Titan 0.5.x (or perhaps earlier).  If so, one solution might be to create a "wrapper graph" to centralize the validation.  The wrapper pattern can be seen in TinkerPop in features like: [ReadOnlyGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/tree/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/wrappers/readonly), [IdGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/tree/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/wrappers/id), etc.  Basically, you create a `ValidationGraph` class and pass your `TitanGraph` instance in on the constructor, then override `addVertex` to intercept the calls.  You can then implement whatever validation you'd like.

In Titan 0.9.x/TinkerPop3, the pattern is a bit different. The current model calls for building a [TraversalStrategy](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0.M8-incubating/#traversalstrategy) to implement the validation.  Unfortunately, this pattern is still a bit unproven.  I'm sure it will develop further after TP3 GA is released.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for the response. I will add in the application level.